# Setting Background Programmatically on Android 3. (setting Background)

Tags: java, android, button

This code is not found in Android 3. Any other style than this?

```
powerButton.setBackground(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lock));
```

The error is this..

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.Button.setBackground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setBackground(Drawable d)` is introduced in API 16 (Jelly Bean). Therefore, you can't use that in API 15 and below.

As alternative, you can use [setBackgroundResource(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

You can also do like this,

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
   powerButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lock));
else
   powerButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lock);
```

Comment: You are a Guru! but one question.. why would they want to introduce that method? setBackground(Drawable d) when it is not usable?

Comment: You mean deprecation, because the method is improved than before, or there is a bug in older method but fixed in new method.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
//  use   setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
 //  use setBackground();
}
```